# True or false( invertibility of $f$)

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ : $(1,10)$  $\to$  $[2,11]$
be a continuous function, then , $f$ cannot be an invertible function.

True/false

Both domain and codomain has same cardinality so we can find a bijection between both sets.
But, the statement is true. What property is used in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a bijection then the inverse would be continuous too and range of the inverse, which is $(0,10)$ would be compact because continuous image of compact sets is compact, This is a contradiction. [A continuous bijection is strictly monotonic and this makes the inverse also monotonic and continuous].

Comment: @WilliamSun Continuous bijections on the real line are known to have continuous inverses automatically. I am assuming this result with a hint that this can b e proved using monotonicity.

Comment: It was very simple to under.stand. Thanks.